# User desktop screen recording in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg, screen-capture

how to recored user desktop video in c# asp.net application, what type of library sdk or nay command line tools required, can we recored user screen in FFmpeg.

Comment: You want to use asp.net to record website visitor's desktops? ...

Answer (score 2):

it's against security principals  of web pages ! you can stream video using prompting user to install plugin you made it to stream your client desktop.
such an example for that Google voice , or currently Hangout, you can modify your plugin to screen users desktop.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Is serverside, All that users can see is some global html codes that all browsers can see, You can't access anything but user's IP using ASP, Programming language that you coded your server on doesn't matter because users doesn't need any runtime to run your web, All you do is sending clients some html codes, You may say C# Is a powerful language and It is, But you that C# You're trying to use Is serverside and for example each button users press will run a specific code on server (And some little design for clients).